# How to use json key with spaces in Vue?

Tags: json, vue.js

Trying to call in this data, but the json key has spaces:

```
{ 52 Week High: 175.99 }

<li>{{ company.52 Week High }}</li>
```

What is the right way to do this? I can't modify the json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```js
company['52 Week High']
```

As long as your data is formatted like this:

```
{ "52 Week High": 175.99 }
```

Working example: [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuPGxpPnt7IGNvbXBhbnlbJzUyIFdlZWsgSGlnaCddIH19PC9saT5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+XG5cbjxzY3JpcHQ+XG5pbXBvcnQgeyBkZWZpbmVDb21wb25lbnQgfSBmcm9tIFwidnVlXCI7XG5leHBvcnQgZGVmYXVsdCBkZWZpbmVDb21wb25lbnQoe1xuICBkYXRhKCkge1xuICAgIHJldHVybiB7XG4gICAgICBjb21wYW55OiB7IFwiNTIgV2VlayBIaWdoXCI6IDE3NS45OSB9XG4gICAgfVxuICB9XG59KTtcbjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuIn0=)